# REDIRECCIONAR + VARIABLES (QUERY) - LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

estoy intentando migrar un proyecto php a Laravel.

En concreto, tengo dudas con este código PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['status'])) {
    @$redir=$_GET['redir'];
    @$redir_r=explode("fas=", $redir);
    @$fas=$redir_r[1];

    if (isset($_GET['iv'])) {
        $iv=$_GET['iv'];
    } else {
        $iv="error";
    }

} else if (isset($_GET['fas']))  {
    $fas=$_GET['fas'];

    if (isset($_GET['iv'])) {
        $iv=$_GET['iv'];
    } else {
        $iv="error";
    }
} else {
    exit(0);
}
```

Quiero controlar las peticiones HTTP mediante un middleware, el cual redirigirá a la página correspondiente según las variables de entrada en la query. Algo similar a esto:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CheckQuery
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
         if($request->auth_get){
            return redirect('auth_get');
        }elseif($request->status){
            echo $request->status;
            return redirect('status');
        }elseif($request->fas && $request->iv){
            return redirect('login');
        }else{
            return redirect('error');
        }
        
    }
}
```

El caso que necesito reenviar esas variables que vienen en la petición GET y estoy intentando hacerlo mediante with(), withInput() y algunas otras que he leído pero no lo consigo ver luego en la vista. Por ejemplo:

```
return redirect('login')->with('fas', $request->fas);
```

Y en la vista:

```
<h1>{{$fas}}</h1>
```

¿Alguna orientación?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

No se si estoy haciendo una salvajada, pero lo he resuelto de la siguiente forma:

```
return redirect()->route('login', ['fas=' . $request->fas, 'iv=' . $request->iv]);
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Sugiero que expliques porque crees que te funciona y así la comunidad tambien podra beneficiarse de ello, si esta respuesta sigue siendo válida para ti, gracias.